# Cropping is not working perfectly as per the frame drawn

Tags: swift, macos, crop, nsimage

I am trying to crop a selected portion of NSImage which is fitted as per ProportionallyUpOrDown(AspectFill) Mode.
I am drawing a frame using mouse dragged event like this:

```
class CropImageView: NSImageView {

    var startPoint: NSPoint!
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var flagCheck = false
    var finalPoint: NSPoint!

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
    
    override var image: NSImage? {
        set {
            self.layer = CALayer()
            self.layer?.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill
            self.layer?.contents = newValue
            self.wantsLayer = true
            super.image = newValue
        }
        get {
            return super.image
        }
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {

        self.startPoint = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        if self.shapeLayer != nil {
            self.shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            self.shapeLayer = nil
        }
        self.flagCheck = true
        var pixelColor: NSColor = NSReadPixel(startPoint) ?? NSColor()
        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
        if pixelColor == NSColor.black {
            pixelColor = NSColor.color_white
        } else {
            pixelColor = NSColor.black
        }
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = pixelColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [1]
        self.layer?.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        var dashAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
        dashAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
        dashAnimation.duration = 0.75
        dashAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        dashAnimation.toValue = 15.0
        dashAnimation.repeatCount = 0.0
        shapeLayer.add(dashAnimation, forKey: "linePhase")
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        let point: NSPoint = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)

        var newPoint: CGPoint = self.startPoint
        
        let xDiff = point.x - self.startPoint.x
        let yDiff = point.y - self.startPoint.y
        let dist = min(abs(xDiff), abs(yDiff))
        newPoint.x += xDiff > 0 ? dist : -dist
        newPoint.y += yDiff > 0 ? dist : -dist
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: self.startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: NSPoint(x: self.startPoint.x, y: newPoint.y))
        path.addLine(to: newPoint)
        path.addLine(to: NSPoint(x: newPoint.x, y: self.startPoint.y))
        path.closeSubpath()
        self.shapeLayer.path = path
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        self.finalPoint = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
    }
}
```

and selected this area as shown in picture using black dotted line:

[image]

My Cropping Code logic is this:

```
// resize Image Methods
extension CropProfileView {

    func resizeImage(image: NSImage) -> Data {

        var scalingFactor: CGFloat = 0.0
        if image.size.width >= image.size.height {
            scalingFactor = image.size.width/cropImgView.size.width
        } else {
            scalingFactor = image.size.height/cropImgView.size.height
        }
        let width = (self.cropImgView.finalPoint.x - self.cropImgView.startPoint.x) * scalingFactor
        let height = (self.cropImgView.startPoint.y - self.cropImgView.finalPoint.y) * scalingFactor
        let xPos = ((image.size.width/2) - (cropImgView.bounds.midX - self.cropImgView.startPoint.x) * scalingFactor)
        let yPos = ((image.size.height/2) - (cropImgView.bounds.midY - (cropImgView.size.height - self.cropImgView.startPoint.y)) * scalingFactor)
        
        var croppedRect: NSRect = NSRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: width, height: height)
        let imageRef = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: &croppedRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
        guard let croppedImage = imageRef?.cropping(to: croppedRect) else {return Data()}
        let imageWithNewSize = NSImage(cgImage: croppedImage, size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))

        guard let data = imageWithNewSize.tiffRepresentation,
              let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: data),
            let imgData = rep.representation(using: .png, properties: [.compressionFactor: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0.25)]) else {
            return imageWithNewSize.tiffRepresentation ?? Data()
        }
        return imgData
    }
}
```

With this cropping logic i am getting this output:

[image]

I think as image is AspectFill thats why its not getting cropped in perfect size as per selected frame. Here if you look at output: xpositon & width & heights are not perfect. Or probably i am not calculating these co-ordinates properly. Let me know the faults probably i am calculating someting wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720720/how-to-crop-a-uiimageview-to-a-new-uiimage-in-aspect-fill-mode - it is for UIKit but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: @matt i agree with you and your answer for iOS platform & i am also trying to follow the same in asked question. However we don't have UIGraphicsImageRenderer() and can't use draw function on CGImage as well. I am not dragging the view however it will be same as i am extracting co-ordinates but still i have a doubt that my x & y coordinates are calculated correctly. Also i would request its not right to make close request for this question as its a different question.

Comment: Are the width and height of the `NSImageView` the same?

Comment: No width, height are not same @Willeke

Comment: When deciding which scaling factor to use you have to take the size of the image view into account. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720720/how-to-crop-a-uiimageview-to-a-new-uiimage-in-aspect-fill-mode

Comment: i am already deciding scaling factor using my CropImageView size. @Willeke

Comment: Could you post the minimal reproducible project to smth like github?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: the `CropImageView` class in the question is a subclass of `NSImageView` but the view is layer-hosting and the image is drawn by the layer, not by `NSImageView`. `imageScaling` is not used.

When deciding **which scaling factor to use** you have to take the size of the image view into account. If the image size is `width:120, height:100` and the image view size is `width:120, height 80` then `image.size.width >= image.size.height` is `true` and `image.size.width/cropImgView.size.width` is `1` but the image is scaled because `image.size.height/cropImgView.size.height` is `1.25`. Calculate the horizontal and vertical scaling factors and use the largest.

See [How to crop a UIImageView to a new UIImage in 'aspect fill' mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720720/how-to-crop-a-uiimageview-to-a-new-uiimage-in-aspect-fill-mode)

Here's the calculation of `croppedRect` assuming `cropImgView.size` returns `self.layer!.bounds.size`.

```
var scalingWidthFactor: CGFloat = image.size.width/cropImgView.size.width
var scalingHeightFactor: CGFloat = image.size.height/cropImgView.size.height
var xOffset: CGFloat = 0
var yOffset: CGFloat = 0
switch cropImgView.layer?.contentsGravity {
    case CALayerContentsGravity.resize: break
    case CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspect:
        if scalingWidthFactor > scalingHeightFactor {
            scalingHeightFactor = scalingWidthFactor
            yOffset = (cropImgView.size.height - (image.size.height / scalingHeightFactor)) / 2
        }
        else {
            scalingWidthFactor = scalingHeightFactor
            xOffset = (cropImgView.size.width - (image.size.width / scalingWidthFactor)) / 2
        }
    case CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspectFill:
        if scalingWidthFactor < scalingHeightFactor {
            scalingHeightFactor = scalingWidthFactor
            yOffset = (cropImgView.size.height - (image.size.height / scalingHeightFactor)) / 2
        }
        else {
            scalingWidthFactor = scalingHeightFactor
            xOffset = (cropImgView.size.width - (image.size.width / scalingWidthFactor)) / 2
        }
    default:
        print("contentsGravity \(String(describing: cropImgView.layer?.contentsGravity)) is not supported")
        return nil
}
let width = (self.cropImgView.finalPoint.x - self.cropImgView.startPoint.x) * scalingWidthFactor
let height = (self.cropImgView.startPoint.y - self.cropImgView.finalPoint.y) * scalingHeightFactor
let xPos = (self.cropImgView.startPoint.x - xOffset) * scalingWidthFactor
let yPos = (cropImgView.size.height - self.cropImgView.startPoint.y - yOffset) * scalingHeightFactor

var croppedRect: NSRect = NSRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: width, height: height)
```

Bugfix: `cropImgView.finalPoint` should be the corner of the selection, not the location of `mouseUp`. In `CropImageView` set `self.finalPoint = newPoint` in `mouseDragged` instead of `mouseUp`.

Comment: @Willleke I really appreciate the time u put to think of something about the question as i am not getting much responses for MacOS, and i tried this solution but it's not making any difference. Because rarely we can find an image which has same width/height property wrt the imageView heights/width for any developer. I already tried a lot from matt's answer which u mentioned and same mentioned in question's comments as well but nothing worked out. After trying those answers this question was put.