# Trying to save merged images but nothing works correctly

Tags: swift, photo

I have looked at every example I can find in previous questions and nothing works. I am merging two images by copying a cropped image to pasteboard and then pasting it in another image view. That works fine but when I try to save it the image is always squished(may be a scale issue but it seems only the vertical size getting distorted.
This is the result of combining the images before trying to save it

[image]

This is after saving the image to the photos album

[image]

The image will not stay in the translated location and it's distorted.
Here is the code when I save the image

```swift
    let fullSize:CGSize = photoView.image!.size
    let newSize:CGSize = fullSize
    let scale:CGFloat = newSize.height/fullSize.height
    let offset:CGFloat = (newSize.width - fullSize.width*scale)/2
    let offsetRect:CGRect = CGRect.init(x: offset, y: 0, width: newSize.width - offset*2, height: newSize.height)
            
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    self.photoView.image!.draw(in: offsetRect)
            
    self.copiedView.image!.draw(in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: photoView.image!.size.width, height:photoView.image!.size.height))
    let combImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                
    //photoView.image = combImage
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `fullSize` is equal to `newSize`, so `scale` is _always_ 1, so `offset` is _always_ 0. Are these intended? You don't seem to be storing the transformation applied to the copied image anywhere...

Comment: To be honest I've tried so many things I started looking at examples and that was the last thing I tried. Thanks, that at least gives me an idea of what to try next.

Comment: Could be a variant of the problem I solve here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43720791/341994

Comment: I'll look at that, thanks. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the copiedView imageview.