# How can I use CGRect() dynamically?

Tags: swift, cgrect

I have the following [scene example](https://i.imgur.com/RzaGJTx.mp4) where I can crop an image based on the selection (red square).

That square has dynamic Height and Width - base on this fact I want to use the selected Height and Width to crop what is inside of the Red square.

The function that I am using for cropping is from [Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping) and looks like this:

```
func cropImage(_ inputImage: UIImage, toRect cropRect: CGRect, viewWidth: CGFloat, viewHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage? 
{    
    let imageViewScale = max(inputImage.size.width / viewWidth,
                             inputImage.size.height / viewHeight)

    // Scale cropRect to handle images larger than shown-on-screen size
    let cropZone = CGRect(x:cropRect.origin.x * imageViewScale,
                          y:cropRect.origin.y * imageViewScale,
                          width:cropRect.size.width * imageViewScale,
                          height:cropRect.size.height * imageViewScale)

    // Perform cropping in Core Graphics
    guard let cutImageRef: CGImage = inputImage.cgImage?.cropping(to:cropZone)
    else {
        return nil
    }

    // Return image to UIImage
    let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
    return croppedImage
}
```

Now. I want to use the given Height and Width to crop that selection.

```
 let croppedImage =  cropImage(image!, toRect: CGRect(x:?? , y:?? , width: ??, height: ??), viewWidth: ??, viewHeight: ??)
```

What should I fill in these parameters in order to crop the image based on the above dynamic selection?

Comment: There's something else missing in this question, where's the code related to the cropping tool? And how are you doing the crop right now?

Comment: That crop tool comes on top of a Camera View - when I am doing the picture I want to save only the selected part. The selection tool (red square) is returning only the Height and Width variables which I suppose to use them in the crop function. Now I am doing the function like I said in the original question, using the cropImage function.

Comment: If the selection tool is only returning hight and width it won't really work. If you're selecting a rectangle, you need to return a rectangle. Without the origin height and width doesn't give you enough information to know what to crop.

Comment: Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720720/how-to-crop-a-uiimageview-to-a-new-uiimage-in-aspect-fill-mode/43720791?r=SearchResults&s=5|34.9765#43720791 ?

Comment: @matt yes, actually that is the case. Now, I have to adapt that solution to SwiftUI approach :) Until now I have the following info: The image, the rectangle thinghy which returns only the height and width  and the crop function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the info from all of your answers and especially @matt's comment and this is the final solution.

Using the input values that my red square returned, I've adapted the original Crop function to this one:

```
    func cropImage(_ inputImage: UIImage, width: Double, height: Double) -> UIImage?
    {

        let imsize = inputImage.size
        let ivsize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        
        var scale : CGFloat = ivsize.width / imsize.width
        if imsize.height * scale < ivsize.height {
            scale = ivsize.height / imsize.height
        }

        let croppedImsize = CGSize(width:height/scale, height:width/scale)

        
        let croppedImrect =
            CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (imsize.width-croppedImsize.width)/2.0,
                                   y: (imsize.height-croppedImsize.height)/2.4),
                   size: croppedImsize)
        
        let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:croppedImsize)
        let croppedIm = r.image { _ in
            inputImage.draw(at: CGPoint(x:-croppedImrect.origin.x, y:-croppedImrect.origin.y))
        }
        
        return croppedIm
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume that your image is in `imageView`, wich is located somewhere in your screen. The `rect` is a variable where your selected frame (related to the imageView.frame) is stored. So the result is:

```
let croppedImage =  cropImage(image!, toRect: rect, viewWidth: imageView.width, viewHeight: imageView.height)
```

Comment: Basically, the crop tool comes on top of a full-screen Camera View. When I am doing the picture I want to save only the selected area.

Comment: ok, try this: let croppedImage =  cropImage(image!, toRect: CGRect(x: rect.x , y: rect.y , width: rect.width, height: rect.heigh), viewWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, viewHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

Comment: what is the point of the construct `toRect: CGRect(x: rect.x , y: rect.y , width: rect.width, height: rect.height)`? Why not just use `toRect: rect` since you're creating a new CGRect with all the same values as rect?

Comment: Ahah, really! I tried to answer quickly and just replaced the author's "??" in the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you just have info of `width` and `height` of the cropping shape. You'll need to calculate the `x` and `y` by yourself.

First, let's consider these information:

```swift
// let's pretend this is a sample of size that your crop tool provides to you
let cropSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 260)
```

Next, you'll need to obtain the **display** size (`width` and `height`) of your image. Display size here is the **frame's size** of your image, not the size of the image itself.

```swift
// again, lets pretend it's just a frame size of your image
let imageSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 480)
```

With this info, you can obtain the `x` and `y` necessary to compose a `CGRect` and then, provide to a cropping function you desire.

```swift
let x = (imageSize.width - cropSize.width) / 2
let y = (imageSize.height - cropSize.height) / 2
```

So now, you can create a rectangle to crop your image like this:

```swift
let cropRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: cropSize.width, height: cropSize.height)
```

With `cropRect` you can use on both `cropping` or `cropImage` functions mentioned in your question.